# Get entire data of a table from sql server to txt file using java

Tags: java, sql-server, text-files

I want to get entire data of table into text file, I used the code as follows

```
 String url = "jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=DBTEST;user=Data;password=123;";
      try {
        Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
try {
      Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url);
      Statement select = con.createStatement();
      ResultSet result = select.executeQuery
                          ("select * from testTable");         

      System.out.println("Got results:");
      System.out.println(result);
      FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("I:/File/InputFile.txt"); 
      BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
      while(result.next()) 
      {  
          try{
                  bw.write(String.valueOf(result.getFloat("XColumn")));; // \n is for to write in a new Line .  
                  bw.newLine();
          }  
          catch (Exception e) {  
              System.out.println("Errrrr......... writing to a file..... :P"+e);  
          }            
      }  
      bw.close();
      select.close();
      con.close();
    }
    catch( Exception e ) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Here I get only corresponding column(XColumn) value as I specified `result.getFloat("XColumn")`. How can I get entire table value?

**Note:** I have table in the format testTable(XColumn,YColumn,ZColumn). I want all the columns values there in txt file.

Comment: To fetch entire table, you have to mention each and every column explicitly.

Comment: You need to use the column name for each of the columns you need to extract from the table.

Comment: You mean something like this `select XColumn,YColumn,ZColumn from testTable`

Answer (score 2):

One option is just retrieve each column because you know its name.

If you do not know its names (because someone may add later more columns), you could retrieve the `ResultSetMetaData` http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#getMetaData().

That metadata will provide the number, name and type of columns returned by the query in the `ResultSet`.

Comment: ResultSetMetaData give you only columns information, not rows value.

Comment: @MasudCSECUET that is what I explained in my post, from that data you can do the proper `rs.getXXXX`.

Answer (score 2):

First of all its not wise to use statement.
To prevent from sql injection,go for preparedStatement.

```
PreparedStatement pt= con.prepareStatement("select * from testTable");
resultSet rs=pt.executeQuery();
while(rs.next())
{
 try{
                  bw.write(String.valueOf(result.getFloat("XColumn")));; // \n is for to write in a new Line .  
                  bw.newLine();
          }  
          catch (Exception e) {  
              System.out.println("Errrrr......... writing to a file..... :P"+e);  
          }   
}
```

If column names are not know then use `ResultSetMetaData`

Comment: If there are no user inputs used to generate the statement, there is no risk of SqlInjection. There is no way the user can alter `select * from testTable`.

Comment: @SJuan76 every time the statement goes to server,then server checks for the syntax and then executes but in preparedstatement server does not check syntax if atleast a similar type has gone to server

Answer (score 2):

You can just extract all columns by number using **ResultSetMetaData**:

```
    ResultSet rs = ...;
    ResultSetMetaData rsmd = rs.getMetaData();
    int columnCount = rsmd.getColumnCount();
    while(rs.next()){
        StringBuilder row = new StringBuilder();
        for(int i = 0; i < columnCount; i++){
            row.append(rs.getObject(i));
        }
    }
```

Comment: Use a `StringBuilder`, never concatenate in a loop.

Comment: @BoristheSpider, btw i'm not a 
    
    `StringBuilder`, but yes, i'm always forget about using that class.

Answer (score 2):

Combine metadate information from ResultSet to get column names

```
ResultSetMetaData metaData = rs.getMetaData();
```

with actual value from columns getting them by index:

```
metaData.getColumnName(i);
rs.getString(i);
```

Answer (score 1):

In `ResultSet`, you can't call all row values at a time. You should do that separately.

Answer (score 0):

```
/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package practice;
import java.io.*;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.ResultSetMetaData;
import java.sql.Statement;


/**
 *
 * @author mahamud.ashik
 */
public class Practice {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    OracleConnectionHandler dbConne =new OracleConnectionHandler();

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        // TODO code application logic here
       try {

           Statement st=OracleConnectionHandler.getConnection().createStatement();
           ResultSet rs=st.executeQuery("select col1,col2,col3 from tableName");


          // for print column name 
           ResultSetMetaData rsmd = rs.getMetaData();


      int numberOfColumns = rsmd.getColumnCount();

      for (int i = 1; i <= numberOfColumns; i++) {
        if (i > 1) System.out.print(",  ");
        String columnName = rsmd.getColumnName(i);
        System.out.print(columnName);
      }
      System.out.println("");
       // write in text file    
            FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("d://stockIn3.txt"); 
      BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);

           while(rs.next()){
               try {
                   String name=rs.getString("col1");
                   String account_no=rs.getString("col2");
                   String sp_id=rs.getString("col3");

               bw.write(name);
               bw.append(";");
               bw.write(account_no);
               bw.append(";");
               bw.write(sp_id);

               bw.newLine();

               }catch (Exception e){
                   System.out.println("Exception"+e);
               }
           }
           bw.close();st.close();
           }

       catch (Exception e){
          System.out.println(e);
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: Using Oracle database connection.